# JPA connection closed with EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

Please excuse the possible improper formatting of this post as I have never posted here before.  I have a Spring MVC web service running that calls into several DAO's that use JPA/hibernate to interact with a SQL Server database.  The connection to the database seems to get closed after the web service has been running for a while.

An example of one of the DAO classes is the following:

```
@Repository
public class OceanClientDaoImpl {

// Create entity manager objects that will talk to the database
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

/**
 * Load all clients in the database. Return as ClientLight objects.
 * 
 * @return List of ClientLight objects.
 */
public List<Client> loadClients() 
{
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    List<?> clients = 
            entityManager.createNativeQuery("select id, clientname, industry, logo, slug from client", 
                    Client.class).getResultList();
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
    return Client.getCheckedList(clients);
}
}
```

The entityManagerFactory is injected via spring in the following way:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"     value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="url" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pw" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.theocean.dao">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
</context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="oceanClientDaoImpl" class="com.theocean.dao.OceanClientDaoImpl">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

This all works fine when I first bring up the application.  The application server is Tomcat.  But, after the application is running for a while, requests to the server start receiving this error:

```
> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/OceanWebService] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed: ] with root cause
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1654)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:4844)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6154)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6106)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1ConnectionCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1756)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectionCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1761)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.setAutoCommit(SQLServerConnection.java:1901)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:58)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    at com.theocean.dao.OceanClientDaoImpl.loadClients(OceanClientDaoImpl.java:52)
    at com.theocean.service.ExperienceClientService.loadClientsLight(ExperienceClientService.java:30)
    at com.theocean.web.ExperienceController.loadClientsLight(ExperienceController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/OceanWebService]     threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed: ] with root cause
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1654)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:4844)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6154)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6106)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1ConnectionCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1756)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectionCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1761)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.setAutoCommit(SQLServerConnection.java:1901)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:58)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    at com.theocean.dao.OceanClientDaoImpl.loadClients(OceanClientDaoImpl.java:52)
    at com.theocean.service.ExperienceClientService.loadClientsLight(ExperienceClientService.java:30)
    at com.theocean.web.ExperienceController.loadClientsLight(ExperienceController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So, the connection is being closed.  Obviously something is wrong with the implementation whether it be the injection method or the method for handling errors, etc.  So, the question is - What is the proper way to do this?  How can I avoid the connection closed error?  Thanks much in advance.

Comment: I suggest you should use connection pool with JPA. You can specify connection pool within entityManagerFactory. Possibly when you specify jpaProperties property of entityManagerFactory. You must be using some sort of JPA vendor like hibernate, eclipselink or toplink etc. Each jpa vendor has different way/properties to use connection pool. You need to refer to their documentation to learn how to use connection pool.

Answer (score 3):

I think what could be happening is that some of the DAO's are leaving database transactions open when an error occurs.

The example DAO above is doing programmatic management of the database transaction, but does not handle the rollback scenario. This is an example of a DAO implementation that would do so:

```
    MyService {

   private EntityManagerFactory emf;

   public void myMethod() {
       EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
       EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
       MyDaoA myDaoA = new MyDaoA(em);
       MyDaoB myDaoB = new MyDaoB(em);
       try {
           tx.begin();
           myDaoA.doSomething();
           myDaoB.doSomething();
           tx.commit();
       } catch(Exception e) {
           tx.rollback();
       }
    }
}
```

All DAOs that do programmatic transaction management should use this pattern, otherwise sooner or later a transaction will not be rolled back and this could cause problems.

A much more frequent and less error prone way of implementing DAOs is to inject directly only an entity manager:

```
MyService {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   @Autowired
   private MyDaoA myDaoA;

   @Autowired
   private MyDaoB myDaoB;

   @Transactional
   public void myMethod() {
      myDaoA.doSomething();
      myDaoB.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Injecting the EntityManagerFactory and doing manual transaction management should be reserved for exceptional cases, and the use of @Transactional be used by default.

Comment: I thought the entityManager was only supposed to live for the lifetime of a single request.  If I inject the entityManager that way won't it live for the entire lifetime of the application?

Comment: What actually gets injected by spring with  PersistenceContext is not an entity manager itself, but an entity manager proxy. If the proxy is configured with PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED) then you have the behaviour you mention. But the normal default case is PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION, which will give you one different entity manager per transaction. This mechanism is transparent and you are always sure that you get the correct entity manager if you use @Transactional.

Comment: I edited my post with the reason why I think this is related, what seems to happen is that due to the way the DAOs are written (no handling for rollbacks if in error, manual transaction handling) some of the DAOs leave transactions open, and connections are leaked. So increasing the connection pool size or switching to another connection pool like c3Po would only mask the real cause of the problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed it to inject the entityManager using the PersistenceContext into the DAO but the issue still happens unfortunately.  I start up the service, wait 20 minutes, make a request and get a connection closed exception.

Comment: Based on the stack trace there was a call to OceanClientDaoImpl, which triggers a call to SessionImpl.beginTransaction, 
which calls the driver to send a command to the SQL server and wait for a reply via TDSReader.readPacket

The root cause is  'SQL Server did not return a response'.  So something happened on the server side which caused the server not to reply.

One explanation is that it's an operational problem on the SQL server caused by an external factor.
one direction is to check with the DBA's if indeeed there are many connections opened on the server and by whom.

Comment: Another explanation is If all DAOs are written like the example, it's likelly that DAOs leave connections open by not calling commit, which causes the
number of maximum connections of the server to be reached, and then the server returns this error. So the fix should be applied to all DAOs (and not only in OceanClientDaoImpl)

Another possible direction is to try another SQL server driver such as http://jtds.sourceforge.net/, but this seems the least likelly solution.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this is the database/azure and not the code.  The database is a SQL Server database on Windows Azure and after some googling it seems like other people have had connection issues with SQL Server on Azure.

Comment: It could be only the database, the DBAs can tell you if there are many connections open and from which machine. It also could be both the code and the DB: the way the DAOs are written can cause connections to leak in case of exceptions, or if somewhere there is a missing commit.  Are all DAOs written with manual transaction handling? Look for exceptions in the server log during the full 20 minutes, a code review on the DAOs could detect missing commits and missing exception handling that could be the source for leaked connections.

Answer (score 0):

I would say problem is with `Connection pooling` , so you can use `c3p0` connection pooling library for fixing your problem, but you should be very carefull with connection pool **properties**.

Actually lot of ways you can do, I am giving you same code for reference. It might help.

Step 1: **persistence.xml**

```
<!-- c3p0 properties -->
        <!-- Determines how many connections at a time c3p0 will try to acquire when the pool is exhausted -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>
        <!-- If this is a number greater than 0, 
        c3p0 will test all idle, pooled but unchecked-out connections, every this number of seconds -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="60"/>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
```

Step 2: And then we create `c3p0.properties` under src/main/resources/META-INF with following properties

```
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
c3p0.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1;
```

Step 3: You need to configure data source

```
<bean id="myJdbcDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
 <!-- Connection properties -->
 <property name="driverClass" value="$DS{database.class}" />
 <property name="jdbcUrl" value="$DS{database.url}" />
 <property name="user" value="$DS{database.username}" />
 <property name="password" value="$DS{database.password}" />
<bean/>
```